# copy files from one path to another path in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, copy

I am new to linux. I am trying to copy files from one path to another path. I have a text file which has all names of files in the following pattern:

```
file-1.txt
file-2.pdf
file-3.ppt
....
```

I created a `.sh` file with the following code:

```
 #!/bin/bash
file=`cat filenames.txt`;
fromPath='/root/Backup/upload/';
toPath='/root/Desktop/custom/upload/';
for i in $file;
do
 filePath=$fromPath$i
 #echo $filePath
 if [ -e $filePath ];
 then
   echo $filePath
   yes | cp -rf $filePath $toPath
 else
   echo 'no files'
 fi
done
```

The above code is copying only the last file name from the text instead of all to the destination path.

Please help.

Comment: working for me..have all files in source directory?

Comment: I have all files in source directory.. but only last file name present in the text file is being copied.. other files are going in to else statement (_as I can see "no files" string in bash_).

Comment: Maybe your file line endings is \n\r or something weird and your script is looking for files `\rfile-3.ppt`...

Comment: `root` should not have a `Desktop`. Log in as yourself and only use `sudo` sparingly.

Comment: @rodrigo: Very good idea. What is the output of `file filenames.txt`?

Comment: @rodrigo I suspect that might happen. but when I do echo to each file name it is showing correct file name. there might be hidden characters though. if so, is there anyway to trim them out?

Comment: @Mr_Green Also convert file to   plain text file using `dos2unix file`.

Comment: @Adaephon `filenames.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`. I think some line terminators are bothering me here. anyway to trim them out?

Comment: `sed 's:\r$::' -i file` will remove `\r` aka *CR* from the line endings in `file`.

Comment: @Adaephon where should I do that? I am new to linux..

Comment: Just on the command line where you also called your script. Go to where your `filenames.txt` is and call `sed 's:\r$::' -i filename.txt`. `sed` is a so called stream editor, you can use it to manipulate texts by certain rules instead of interactively. `s:pattern:replacement:` is the rule for _s_ubstitution, it replaces a matching `pattern` with `replacement`, `\r` is the escape code for *CR* and `$` is the symbol for *end of line*.

Comment: @Adaephon Thanks it is working fine :). please post as answer whenever you have time. Thank you again.

Comment: @Mr_Green the script itself looks fine. Just as a note: you do not need `yes |` if you are using `cp` with `-f`. `-f` means *force* and essentially tells `cp` that you are really sure. In fact you actually need the option `-i` to be even asked for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to loop over a set of input lines is

```
while read i; do
    : something with "$i"
done <filenames.txt
```

Note the use of double quotes around `"$i"` and generally variable interpolation where the string contains a filename component. Unquoted values are only appropriate when you specifically require the shell to do word splitting and wildcard resolution.

Comment: Vaguely also check that you don't have DOS line endings in the input file.